# How to create object of Date("23.03.2010")

Tags: javascript

I have astring directly coming form the database and I am creating object of Date as
`Date dt=Date("23.03.2010")` and it is comin NaN

whereas when I use `Date dt= Date("03/23/2010")` it works fine.

Any Idea how I can get this working?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string from the database and then create the date object. You will have to subtract 1 from the parsed month value to get a correct date.

```
var dateString = "23.03.2010";
var dateParts = dateString.split(".");
var dt = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must pass string (parsed) dates in MDY format. This is to prevent ambiguity (does 5/6/2010 mean 6th May or 5th June?)

If you prefer, you can use `new Date(year, month, day)` format, and pass the arguments separately.

Comment: that should be  `6th May or 5th june` .. :)

Comment: I always find it funny that `m/d/y` should prevent ambiguity as it's only used in a pretty minuscule part of the world; I'd say most people would find it more confusing than ISO 8601 ;-)

Comment: I'm from the UK, I agree wholeheartedly :) d/m/y would be sensible, and y/m/d the least ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way if is you can return the date as milliseconds since 1970-01-01, then you can easily create a Date object from it. Example:

```
var n = 1269302400000;
var dt = new Date(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll want to invoke `Date` with the `new` operator - [from the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date):

> Invoking Date in a non-constructor
>   context (i.e., without the new
>   operator) will return a string
>   representing the current time.

The same page details the syntax of the `Date` constructor.

If you are constructing a `Date` from a string the format accepted is governed by the rules of the `Date.parse` method. See [Microsoft's `Date.parse` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4w173wk(VS.85).aspx) for a summary of these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
var dateParts = '23.03.2010'.split('.');
// -1 from month because javascript months are 0-based
var dateObj = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0]);
```

Comment: That would give you a Date object with the month april, not march.

Comment: The month will be off by one since the second argument to the `Date` constructor is a number in the range 0-11.

Comment: @Martin: really? JavaScript has the same braindead API as Java in that respect?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
d="23.03.2010".split(".");
Date dt=Date([d[1],d[0],d[2]].join("/"))
```

i think it isn't the most beautiful way.